# array push in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have code flow like

```
 $titlecriteria=array();
 $title = new MongoRegex("/^$tag/i");                    
 $titlearray= array("title" => $title);
 array_push($titlecriteria,$titlearray);
```

consider I have two titles like 'abc','def'

If i do like this, then the $titlecriteria will look like

```
  array(2) (
    [0] => array(1) (
   [title] => MongoRegex object {
    regex => (string) ^abc 
   flags => (string) i
     }
   )
   [1] => array(1) (
   [title] => MongoRegex object {
    regex => (string) ^def 
   flags => (string) i
     }
    )
  )
```

ie the value is inside another array..I also tried array_merge().As the key title is same it takes the last value alone. I need output like

```
array(2) (
 [title] => MongoRegex object {
  regex => (string) ^abc 
  flags => (string) i
 }
 [title] => MongoRegex object {
  regex => (string) ^def 
  flags => (string) i
 }
)
```

ie the all the values are in same array. Is this possible? help me out

Comment: It's not possible for array to contain two elements with the same key

Comment: You can't have all your array elements share the same key ("title"). Try $titlearray= array($tag => $title); and see if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

How can you use two same key name in a particular array.

You can directly insert a object into a array.

For Eg:

```
  $title=array();
  $obj1=new MongoRegex("/^$tag/i");
  $obj2=new MongoRegex("/^$tag/i");
  array_push($title,$obj1);
  array_push($title,$obj2);
```

Then Accesslike this:

```
 foreach($title as $obj){
   $obj; // Your MongoRegex Object 
 }
```